# Add/Remove margin when removing adView

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

Is it possible to remove the margin/padding of my FAB button when the user purchases in-app purchase. 
The adview will be bellow my FAB button, but I want to remove it (and push the FAB to where the adview was).

this is how my layout looks like [image] 
my main activity xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            xmlns:materialdesign="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/tool_bar">
</include>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tool_bar"/>

<TextView android:id="@+id/list_empty"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="No Shopping Items yet"
          android:layout_centerVertical="true"
          android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<com.software.shell.fab.ActionButton
    android:id="@+id/buttonFloat"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    fab:show_animation="@anim/fab_roll_from_down"
    fab:hide_animation="@anim/fab_roll_to_down"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
</com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Comment: Yes it is. But a lazy approach might be to have two layouts and swap them out based on the purchase state. Otherwise, you have to use LayoutParams and set them on the view at runtime. You should be careful and probably stick to Relative Layout params for better layout and device support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-read your question:

One solution:
If you layer your FAB button view on top of the AdView, using a LinearLayout, changing the visibility of the AdView to "GONE" will allow the FAB view to automatically drop to where the AdView was. If you post your XML code it will be easier to help you out. A picture doesn't tell me what layout objects you are using.

One Example, assuming Layout has AdView with id="my_adview":

```
View addView = findViewById(R.id.my_adview);
if ( purchased) {
addView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that is going to work perfectly for my purpose. Very smart approach. BTW, I updated my question with my activity main xml code.